# Dynamic component insertion using VueJs, Cordava and Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, dynamic

Using *vuejs* and *Cordova*, I could not dynamicaly insert/create a new *v-select* component.
**My goal** is to duplicate and insert a copy an existing *v-select* when my "Add" button gets clicked.

The code of my page is:

```
<v-select
    :items="exerciceList" 
    v-model="selectedExercice" 
    label="pick an exercise" 
    v-validate="'required'" 
    data-vv-name="select"
    required>
</v-select>
</div>
<div id="selectsContainer"></div>
<v-btn flat icon id="btn" v-on:click="newExercice()">
```

My (not working) click event listener:

```
methods: {
    newExercice: function () {
      var container = document.getElementById('selectsContainer');
      var select = document.getElementById('exo');

      // select.items = this.exerciceList;
      select.removeAttribute('id');
      select.style.display = 'block';
      container.appendChild(select);
    }
  },
```

The item with the id expo's code:

```
<v-select
  id="exo"
  style="display: none;"
  :items="exerciceList"
  v-model="selectedExercice"
  label="Choisissez un exercice"
  v-validate="'required'"
  data-vv-name="select"
  required>
```

Thank you for helping me improve my implementation.

Comment: Manipulating the DOM is not a good solution here. If you use a method, you should think it the VueJS way. Did you have a look at dynamics components? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Answer (score 1):

What Michael S has said is correct, you do not want to manipulate the DOM directly, causes many issues. Probably the best solution (quick and easy anyway) would be to import that additional v-select component and then add it dynamically with a simple list or in this case an integer increase.

If you're wanting to get a little more customized with it, you can create an object and add and remove styles, attr, etc. from it dynamically the same way this option would work but turning item into an array of objects. then proceed to add an object to it whenever the button is clicked.

```
<v-select
    :items="exerciceList" 
    v-model="selectedExercice" 
    label="pick an exercise" 
    v-validate="'required'" 
    data-vv-name="select"
    required>
</v-select>
</div>
<div id="selectsContainer"
  v-for="(item, idx) in items">
    <v-select
    id="item.id" <!-- or use idx -->
    style="item.style" <!-- or use any string statement -->
    ...etc
    >
</div>
<v-btn flat icon id="btn" v-on:click="newExercice()">

...{
     components: [componentName],
     data: return {
       items: 0,
       ...
     }
     methods: {
       newExercice: ()=>{
         this.items++
       }
     }
...}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check that